# how to load an html file locally into the uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

i am having problem with how to get the uiwebview loaded with local html file .provide the cod e as well i am having the hmtl file as fp_dis-1.html. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
UIWebView *page;

[page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your-local-file-url" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```